# codeigniter: how to reduce load

Tags: php, codeigniter

**Problem**: I have a table which stores the users setting. Every controller's function needs to check this setting before execution to verify user setting for this function.

**My Solution**: I have created a model which I loaded in the autoloader and inside this model, there is a function `check_user_setting()` which check user setting for this function for that user from the database every time when the function is called and return `TRUE` and `FALSE` base on a setting.

**Expected solution**: when every time to check user setting form database it connects to the database and fetch data (it time-consuming) I want to do it one time it fetches data from the database and stores this array and base on this array it checks setting on every function. How and where I store this array which value will remain static for that system. How can I do this? or there is the better way of doing this.

Comment: put as static array in model and call DB only if it not initialized

Comment: can you please provide me a sample code is very helpful for me

Comment: `static $arr = [];`

Comment: Clear and load the user's settings into a session variable once per page load and have `check_user_setting()` check against the session variable instead of performing the query. If you do not want to use the session variable then you can declare a static variable within `check_user_setting()` or declare a private variable within `check_user_setting()`'s class and check against that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query caching in codeigniter. [Query caching](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/caching.html)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem a few months ago, basically a needed to filter the queries based on some values asigned to the user (users table).
What i did was to store those "setting" in the session

```
$this->session->settingArray = $settingsFromDatabase;
$this->session->otherConstantStuffInTheSession = $arrayFromDb;
```

Hope my answer helps u.

Answer (score 0):

A base controller is one possible solution. The base might look something like

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{

  protected $user = [];

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user_settings');
    $this->user = $this->user_settings->getUserSettings($id);
  }

}
```

You extend any controller that needs to access user settings using `MY_Controller`.

So, if `getUserSettings($)` returns `array("id"=>'dave')` and if the controller `Test` extends `MY_Controller` like this

```
class Test extends MY_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->user['id'];
    }
}
```

A request to `http://example.com/test` would output "dave".

`MY_Controller.php` should be in */application/core/* and `config.php` should contain this setting

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```